# When applying multi-row boolean arrays to filter multi-row arrays, the final array is 1D. Is there a way to separate this array into its original rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

You can filter numpy arrays using a boolean array

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
a_bool = np.array([True, False, True])
a[a_bool]
```

```
array([1, 3])
```

You can also do the same with multiple rows, however the final arrays is only 1D, the row from which each value came from is not preserved

```
td = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] )
tb = np.array([[True, False, True], [False, True, False]])
td[tb]
```

```
array([1, 3, 5])
```

Since numpy can't do ragged tensors, what could be the most computationally efficient way to separate the 1D array by the rows in which the value came from?

```
array([1, 3])
array([5])
```

I came up with

```
tb.sum(axis=1)
```

Which gives the number of True values per row. Then I tried

```
np.split(td[tb], tb.sum(axis=1))
```

But that results in an empty array in the middle

```
[array([1, 3]), array([], dtype=int64), array([3, 5])]
```

I tried an expanded case to see if the persists along the even number arrays

```
td = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]] )
tb = np.array([[True, False, True], [False, True, False], [False, False, False], [True, True, False]])
np.split(td[tb], tb.sum(axis=1))
```

```
[array([1, 3]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 3]),
 array([ 5, 10, 11])]
```

However, the split stops working, since the 2nd arg to split is the indices for the array.

Comment: With `cumsum`: `np.split(td[tb], tb.sum(1).cumsum()[:-1])`

Comment: This solved it, if you submit as an answer I will approve it

Comment: In most cases working with lists of `np.array` is not a particularly practical approach (You lose most of the benefits of `numpy`). Masking with `np.ma.masked_array(td, ~tb)` might be a better solution.

Comment: There's some sort of trade off between splitting after the whole mask, and just iterating through and applying the mask row by row.  `np.split` has to iterate through, taking slices.  Anytime you expect a list of arrays that differ in size, you have to do some sort of Python level iteration.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny in my case, I'm trying to get all possible combinations of each number in the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
np.array([row[row != 0] for row in np.multiply(td,tb)])
```

output:

```
[array([1, 3]) array([5])]
```

edit: it might be more efficient to have a 2d array as an output and just accept zeros or `None` for elements that correspond to `False`. But this depends on what you want to do with it.